# Как firefox 57 разрешить открывать локальные файлы (file:///) расширениям?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extension

Кароче есть у меня локальный `.html` файл, который мне нужно чтобы открывался при открытии новой вкладки, ну и при запуске браузера также. Раньше эту задачу я решал дополнением\расширением "**New Tab Homepage**" и установив на домашнюю страницу ссылку на локальный файл `"file:///C:/index.html"`. Теперь же не прокатывает т.к.  "Доступ к локальным файлам по URL-адресу больше невозможен для расширений`.

Может в `about:config` можно прописать ссылку на локальный файл для открытия в новых вкладках не заморачиваясь с дополнениями? хотя.. "Since Firefox 41 it's no longer possible to customize the page shown in a new tab via changing the preference `browser.newtab.url` in `about.config.` Because of the fact that hijackers abused the preference in the past, Mozilla decided to remove it. "

Буду благодарен за помощь в решении этой задачи любым способом.

*ссылка где поднимают данную тему - [ссылка.](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/opening-links-to-local-files-file/16449/7)

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/

Comment: New Tab Override тоже не пашет!